# Div overflow scrollbar on top of the content?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a div with the content set for `overflow: auto` and `height: 300px`. There's a table within that div so, when the table has more content than the div is high, the content scrolls.

The problem I'm having is that the scrollbar is sitting on top of my image that I've got on the right of the table.

Is there a way to push the scrollbar beyond the content?

Comment: The div needed some padding on the right... simple, I know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm getting your problem right, I'd apply a `padding-right` to the surrounding div container to get the table away from the edge where the scrollbar will be shown.

Comment: I was soooo tired yesterday that I couldn't even see the code. It was frustrating me so much that I couldn't wrap my head around the simple solution. This is it... of course. Thank you, zero.